# How to set column width in R Shiny data table?

Tags: javascript, html, r, shiny, rstudio

I am building a Shiny dashboard displaying a DataTable.

My objective is to have the column width of data table automatically adjusted to fit the cell values in 1 line instead of multiple lines. However, I got the following result:

[image]

It seems like **Name** was adjusted as what I want, but **Notes** did not. Then, I followed those links: 
https://rstudio.github.io/DT/options.html,

[Setting column width in R Shiny DataTable does not work in case of lots of column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34850382/setting-column-width-in-r-shiny-datatable-does-not-work-in-case-of-lots-of-colum),

[R Shiny set DataTable column width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25205410/r-shiny-set-datatable-column-width)

Basically, the solutions suggested online were to use `autoWidth = TRUE` argument with `columnDefs`when rendering data table.

This did not work for me as well, below is the result:

[image]

It seems like the width of the table was narrowed comparing with the initial result

Below is my final code:

```
header <- dashboardHeader(
  title = "Test"
)

sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(
)

body <- dashboardBody(
            box(title = "Test", width = 7, status = "warning", DT::dataTableOutput("df"))
)

# UI
ui <- dashboardPage(header, sidebar, body)

# Server
server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$df = DT::renderDataTable(df, options = list(
    autoWidth = TRUE,
    columnDefs = list(list(width = '10px', targets = c(1,3)))))
    }

# Shiny dashboard
shiny::shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I am not sure why the width of **Name** column can be adjusted with the length of cell value, but that of **Notes** cannot. I also tried using data table in other projects, the width of the columns can only be adjusted with the length of **column name**.

Another option in my case would be setting the column width to be only a certain number of characters and having the full context of cell values showing up by hovering over the cell. The solution was suggested here: [R Shiny Dashboard DataTable Column Width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55165477/r-shiny-dashboard-datatable-column-width). However, this is for DT only, but it did not work out when I integrate it in Shiny.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: *"However, this is for DT only, but it did not work out when I integrate it in Shiny."* I don't think so.The answer I gave [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55165477/r-shiny-dashboard-datatable-column-width) should work in Shiny as well.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want multiple lines, you can add the CSS property `white-space: nowrap` to the cells in the columns you want.

Since you're in Shiny, it is easy to do so, by defining a CSS class and assigning it to the columns with `className` in the `columnDefs` option:

```
library(DT)
library(shiny)

dat <- data.frame(
  V1 = c("A", "B"),
  V2 = c(
    "A cool guy living in US and Canada", 
    "A cool guy living in California"
  ),
  V3 = c(
    "A cool guy living in US and Canada", 
    "A cool guy living in California"
  ),
  V4 = c(
    "A cool guy living in US and Canada", 
    "A cool guy living in California"
  ),
  V5 = c(
    "A cool guy living in US and Canada", 
    "A cool guy living in California"
  ),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

css <- "
.nowrap {
  white-space: nowrap;
}"

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$style(HTML(css))
  ),
  DTOutput("table")
)

server <- function(input, output){

  output[["table"]] <- renderDT({
    datatable(dat, 
              options = list(
                columnDefs = list(
                  list(className = "nowrap", targets = "_all")
                )
              ))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the index for column widths is base 0, not 1. In the OP code, the target sets the width (to a relatively narrow 10px) for columns 2 and 4, not 1 and 3.

Try the following,

> columnDefs = list(list(width = '200px', targets = c(0,2)))))

This should make the first and third columns a 200px, while all others are auto width.